# Android how to receive list object from server?

Tags: android

Idea:

From android

Sendind to server:--username and country name
receive from server :-- some details of the user.

So, I have 
**server send to android**

```
List<User> findUser=userDao.findUser(sff.getFullname(), sff.getCountry());
for (User usser : findUser) {
logger.info(usser.getCountry());
}
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(findUser, HttpStatus.OK);
```

**Client code connecting & receiving data from server**

```
  @Override
    public String userSearch(String fullname, String country) throws Exception {
    // initialise URL for mobile user sign up POST
    String url1 = PE_URL + PE_SEARCHBYNAME;
    // Instantiate and initialise a SignupForm
    SearchUser su = new SearchUser(fullname, country);
    URL url = new URL(url1);
    String urlParameters = "suf="+ URLEncoder.encode(new Gson().toJson(su), "UTF-8");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(urlParameters.getBytes().length);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Application-Id",
            "Ajrehrwweg22");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    try {

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.print(urlParameters);
    out.close();
    // build the string to store the response text from the server
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(inputLine);
    }

    Log.d("MyApp", TAG + " > server  response result: " + sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    throw new Exception(sb.toString());

    }
    }
```

**MainActivity background code**

```
private void serverSearchUser(final SearchUser su) {
AsyncTask<SearchUser, Void, String> execute = 
new AsyncTask<SearchUser, Void, String>() {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(SearchUser... params) {
String serverResponse = "";
try {
serverResponse = mServerAuth.userSearch(su.getFullname(), suff.getCountry());


} catch (Exception e) {

}
return serverResponse;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String serverResponse) {

// do we have the authtoken?
if (serverResponse instanceof String) {

SearchUser suf = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse, SearchUser.class);

} else {
// we have an error in the data sent
Error error;
try {
error = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse, Error.class);
EditText errorField = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name)
    .findViewWithTag(error.getField());
if (errorField != null) {
try {
errorField.setError(URLDecoder.decode(error.getMessage(), "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

}}}catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
                }}}

        }.execute();
    }
```

From server successfully sends data to android But In android response
 I am getting error:

```
access server error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

Comment: I dont no which library you are using but i suggest you to use android volley to communicate with server it's easy and fast

Comment: Use JsonArray to store list of Objects and send it to client side.

Comment: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
take look at your json object structure. Its at starting only expectation is json object but its starting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe GSON returns you an array of USER type while you are trying to get a single object from the response. Print the response on logcat..
try to change

```
SearchUser suf = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse, SearchUser.class);
```

to

```
SearchUser[] suf = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse, SearchUser[].class);
```